# Invalid specification in write.table()

Tags: r, write.table

I am encountering suddenly this odd error, which I have never come across before in `write.table()` command:

```
write.table(items,file="E:/CFA/items.dat",sep="\t",row.names=F,col.names=F) 
Error in write.table(items, file = "E:/CFA/items.dat",  : 
  invalid 'row.names' specification
```

When taking away the `row.names` argument, there is still the same error with `col.names` one. The data is a data frame which I have already worked with several times with no difficulties to create a `.dat` file. I am just puzzled.

Does anybody have a clue why it's happening now?

Thanks beforehand

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Is it possible you have reassigned the F variable somewhere? Try doing it using `FALSE` instead of F.

`write.table(items,file="E:/CFA/items.dat",sep="\t",row.names=FALSE,col.names=FALSE)`

Comment: Surprisingly, that was it! now I just wonder where it came out from... Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

Try write.table(items,file="E://CFA//items.dat",sep="\t",row.names=F,col.names=F)

or rm(F,T) and then your command.